# Ensure TeamCity fails when it's checkout fails

Tags: teamcity

Obviously the first thing our TeamCity builds do is to get the latest source. What is happening is that this is silently failing, but not actually checking out *ALL* of the source. I would like the build to immediately fail on this step, and not later when it tries to build something that hasn't been checked out.

[NB The underlying issue causing this is that our TFS server has run out of disc space, but I would want TeamCity to fail immediately if there are checkout issues - something I would have though it should do by default]

NB TeamCity 2023.05 (build 129203). Checkout on Agent.